# How do I delete all remote branches in a folder/namespace?

Tags: git

I would like to delete all remote branches that were created in a folder. Is there a git command that accomplishes this?

Folder here refers to the `foo` in `git push origin HEAD:foo/bar`.

For example, suppose I have a bunch of remote branches I created under the 'foo' folder.

```
$ git ls-remote | grep foo
6a921de080afbc24fd5a9513a70fbf5480997deb        refs/heads/foo/dev1
5de89077ff5d5815fa6d1bed9f7a77ccbee99d90        refs/heads/foo/dev2
07afb7d3c130104f7d2bd26e6e41bde7d4509f00        refs/heads/foo/dev3
ade2b64dc76ed51cfa14d2de01e9f2439692ebfd        refs/heads/foo/dev4
c702e3e2136b290efa5d45d878c8d85c11171b6e        refs/heads/foo/dev5
1869a9c43038b08718746067e64c8e6b4f8aa9af        refs/heads/foo/dev6
e7fe6297f94ae58afc3ef16090d08dcd6ee22512        refs/heads/foo/dev8
6ec6005b3aeea44214eef958a1a97377e57920b9        refs/heads/foo/dev9
```

I know that I can delete a single branch by running:

```
git push origin :foo/dev1
```

I was hoping I could run this to delete all branches that are in the `foo` folder but it doesn't work since `foo/*` is not a valid ref:

```
git push origin :foo/*
```

Do I instead need to write a script to delete each branch individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a *script* per se, but you do need one refspec per name to delete:

```
git push origin --delete foo/dev1 foo/dev2 foo/dev3 foo/dev4 ... foo/dev9
```

for instance.  The `--delete` flag is handy here, as otherwise you need:

```
git push origin :foo/dev1 :foo/dev2 :foo/dev3 ... :foo/dev9
```

The tricky thing here is that although these names force you to treat them as if they were folder-structured,<sup>1</sup> they really aren't, internally.  So if you'd like to automatically have `*` expand, you would have to write your own program (script or not) that does this kind of expansion.

---

<sup>1</sup>By this I mean that if you have a branch or remote-tracking name of the form `A` you cannot have one of the form `A/B`, even though *internally*, Git could handle this just fine.  The reason for imposing this limitation is that Git will sometimes—but not always—store these names in actual files and paths on host systems, and those host systems impose the restrictions.  Git is acquiring a new reference storage system that would never have this issue, but it isn't out yet.